# Test my forms for proper query escaping

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-injection, datamapper

CodeIgniter claims do sanitize POST variables. I'm also using [DataMapper](http://stensi.com/datamapper/) which I believe also does it's own thing. I would like to double check to make sure it's doing what it's supposed to be doing. How can I do this?

I'd like to test this without destroying anything, would typing random escaped characters work? What should I see entered into the database vs. what I typed?

Can anyone confirm that CI and DataMapper do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if what you type is the same as what's in your database.  If it isn't, it's probably doing something...

Script characters should be escaped to their html entity equivalent I'm assuming.

Comment: But what should I see entered into the database? Should it be the code or should I just wait till it doesn't fully execute the query?

Comment: I use CI a lot, though not DataMapper, so I know that it does sanitise your data for you. However, if you want to run some tests, read a page like http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html about SQL injection attacks for example code you can enter into your forms. If something goes wrong, then you know CI or DataMapper have a problem.